# Why does a SqlConnection get closed mid-transaction?

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

In code that simplified looks something like the following, `conn2.Open()`, executed less than 1 second after the transaction was started (i.e. no timeout issue) sometimes throws, claiming the (ambient) transaction had already been aborted - in other words, conn2 is not the problem.

```
using (var ts1 = new TransactionScope(...))
{
    using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connStr1))
    {
        conn1.Open();
        var cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
        // use cmd1 .. 
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connStr2))
    {
        conn2.Open(); // THIS SOMETIMES THROWS
        // ...
    }

    ts1.Complete();
}
```

Every time this exception has occurred so far, the logs indicate that between the failing transaction and the last transaction before it there are at least 4.5 long minutes without any transaction, so it looks like perhaps a TCP connection could have timed out.

But if e.g. conn1 had timed out, it would already throw on `conn1.Open()`. Instead it throws on `conn2.Open()`, indicating that `conn1` had been closed.

**So what happened to `conn1` and why? And why is it only indicated when calling `conn2.Open()`?**

When trying to reproduce the problem with above code, by manually killing the TCP connection underlying `conn1` after calling `conn1.Dispose()`, I can reproduce almost the exact same stack trace occurring on `conn2.Open()`. Only the `InvalidOperationException` turns into a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`, everything else is 100% identical. But between the activity in conn1 and the successful `conn1.Dispose()` and `conn2.Open()` almost no time elapses, so it cannot be a timeout.

This is on

- WindowsServer 2008R2
- .Net 3.5
- SQLServer 2008R2

---

The exception and stack trace:

```
System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted.
 ---> System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException: Failure while attempting to promote transaction.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.Promote()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.Promote()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CheckForFinishedTransaction(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.GetTransactionCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereAbouts)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at My.Code...
```

---

**Edit** (addressing a proposed answer)

Can it be a timeout? As I mentioned, the error occurs less than 1 sec into the transaction, so (absent some weird bug) **it cannot be a mereTransaction/TransactionScope/DTC timeout** (which are all set north of 30 seconds).

Fwiw, this is what a DTC timeout after `conn1.Dispose()` and before `conn2.Open` would have looked like (on a Japanese language OS).

```
System.Transactions.TransactionException: トランザクションの状態に対して操作が有効ではありません。
 ---> System.TimeoutException: トランザクションがタイムアウトしました。
   --- 内部例外スタック トレースの終わり ---
   場所 System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   場所 System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   場所 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   場所 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   場所 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   場所 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   場所 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   場所 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

Comment: Is there any firewalls between application server and the sql server?

Comment: If you open more than one connection to the database within a transaction scope the transaction will be promoted to a Distributed Transaction, And perhaps there is some problems with the DTC on the servers?

Comment: @JoãoSilva No firewall, just a switch or two.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky did you find a resolution ?

Comment: @wal Unfortunately not. I'm not sure if it is still happening, but meanwhile most of the DB stuff for that project has been moved to Oracle, maybe that's why I'm not hearing about it any more...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with your DTC Timeout which is timed out at the moment you are stating the second connection and promote the transaction to a dtc transaction. You can change the time out in the machine settings. You change the timeout for all DTC transaction, so you can have a performance impact when changing it to a large value.

A 10 min timeout in machine.config:

```
<configuration>
 <system.transactions>
   <machineSettings maxTimeout="00:10:00" /> 
 </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why do you think it is a DTC timeout? The innermost stack frame seems to be `SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction`, which indicates the original problem to be closer to the SqlConnection side of things. Also, I added to my question and reiterated why I don't think it can be a simple timeout, and for the particular case of a DTC timeout (which was easy enough to reproduce) I pasted the stack trace, which is quite different from the one I'm getting in production.

Comment: I've seen exactly this stacktrace on a dtc timeouts. Check all your configurations and test with a larger timeout. Check also if you have the correct configuration for 64/32 bit.

Comment: By "exactly this stacktrace", do you mean just the outer exception (starting from `TransactionStateAborted.CheckForFinishedTransaction`) or really the exact same two inner exceptions as well, including `SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction`?

Comment: The timeout settings are fine. But could it perhaps be an idle timeout (I mentioned the idle period which so far always preceded that error) that disconnects a TCP (?) **connection to the MSDTC, which sat idle for too long in some connection pool**, and when the promoter tries to re-use it, it - sometimes - fails?

Comment: Meanwhile, I checked the aggregated dtc statistics in *component services* on the machine in question, and it turned out there are 4 aborted dtc transactions for every committed one! (committed: 77k, aborted: 369k) Something is clearly wrong here. Still not sure if the DTC aborts the transactions, but I know where to direct my investigation.